# IDE Eclipse async function ()

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Estoy realizando uno function async en javascript y si funciona. Mi problema viene cuando uso formatter en todo el documento. En vez de quedar de la siguiente forma.

```
async function(){}
```

El formatter lo deja así, con una línea debajo.

```
async 
function (){}
```

De esta forma recibo el siguiente error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: async is not defined at

Alguna porfa de poder solucionarlo uso IDE Eclipse.